# Fix the FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core error reliably

Tags: f#

In most machines I get an error when trying to use anything that depends on FSharp.Core, the error is:

```
FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core
```

I have found a work around by copying sigdata and opdata as well as Fsharp.Core.dll to the executing location, however I think this is not a very clean solution, particularly if this solution is used by people outside my organization.

I also thought maybe there is a Fsharp.core 4.3.0.0 nuget package but, that doesn't seem to be the case (that is my minimum required version)

Any ideas how to solve the problem once and for all?

Comment: What library you tries to use (that depend on `FSharp.Core`)? Moreover  you should not copy `FSharp.Core.dll` to target directory. As I know such error may happened when you use wrong version of `FSharp.Core.dll` in runtime.

Comment: Hi, It's FSharp.Compiler.Service. I know I shouldn't copy it (hence the question) but it seems to be the only workaround that works (excuse the pun)

Comment: Strange, it should be fixed in latest versions... https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues/38

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried with updating to the latest FSharp.Compiler.Services and still the problem persists. I also tried setting the f# version to 4.3.1 and no luck. Anything else you think I should try?

Comment: Could you share project/solution that does not work?

Comment: Just had this same problem in another context. When building a console app for use as an Azure WebJob the build of the website fails if the console app is targeting F# 3.1, but works for 3.0. I need to package up a bug report to Kevin.

Comment: @sergeyTihon sure, it's open source and available here https://github.com/BraveSirAndrew/DualityScripting you'll encounter this problem when running from within the main project duality https://github.com/BraveSirAndrew/duality.

Comment: Thanks @jackFox  I'll re-target to 3.0 and report